# Partial Curl View - iPhone - Data Transfer

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, ios5

I have an issue with navigating from  one view to another view using partial curl on Xcode 4.2.

**My Task**:

I click a button on first view and then second view appear as partial curl way *(Xcode 4.2 story board)*. And then I select a value from a picker on second view then I go back to first view again. Then I need to show that value on first view button label text.

How could I do this?

---

Answer (score 0):

The code is `[self presentViewController:yourModalVC animated:YES completion:^{ }];`

However, to do it in your storyboard, select the second view controller and choose Transition Style > Partial Curl in the inspector. Then Control Click from your button to this view controller. This creates a segue. Finally, choose Modal on the segue.

Comment: @akaru :

how could I do it ?

think we are passing a string called akaru then how could we pass in to text field on first view.?

I cannt understand what you means by completion:^{ }

Comment: read the docs for that method. you will need to use it, as data cannot be passed when using the storyboard. you'll need to set a property on the vc you're presenting, then present it via that method.

Comment: @akaru: 
I know how to add a view as partial way and I did that. And Now I selected a value from Data picker. So I need to pass my selected value to previous view. I means when I was touch on upper part of second view then first view will appear. At that time I need to pass value. So Can you send me the code for that?

Passing value to second view to first view?